# Is it safe to expose your Fabric API key?

Tags: api-key, twitter-fabric

I have an app on the App Store that I wish to make open source. I need to know if it is okay to expose the Fabric API key and build secret on a public github repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, definitely don't do that.  Someone could produce an app that destroys your analytics, release malevolent beta apps, etc.